# How to calculate the following integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

How the calculate the following integrals? Therein $D$ is a constant.

$$(1)\;\;\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1-D\cdot\cos\theta} d\theta$$

and

$$(2)\;\;\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+D\cdot\cos\theta} d\theta$$

Comment: I suppose $d\theta$ is in the numerator?

Comment: Thanks for your checking, $d\theta$ is not in the numerator, I re-edit the problem

Comment: What is the difference between $(1)$ and $(2)$? 

Also have you tried to use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution ? After splitting the interval from $0, \pi$ to $\pi , 2\pi$ cause $\tan \frac{x}{2}$ is undefined there.

Comment: Aren't those two integrals the very same one...?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Salut Claude, mon ami!

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for checking, I re-edited the problems

Comment: @JLiu Have you already studied complex integration?

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for your reply. I am sorry I have not studied such a method.

Comment: @Jliu Ok, Then, I think, it is going to be solving that real integral, and that can result in very ugly primitive functions...

Answer (score 2):

$$I_2=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+D\cos(\theta)}=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+D\cos(\theta)}+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+D\cos(\theta)}$$ Let $\theta=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$
$$I_2=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+D\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\frac{2dx}{1+x^2}+\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{1}{1+D\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\frac{2dx}{1+x^2}=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2+D-Dx^2}=2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(1-D)x^2+(1+D)}=\frac{2}{1-D}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+\frac{1+D}{1-D}}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-D^2}}$$ Hopefully all my computation is correct, the other integral can be done in the same way. Just use [Weierstrass Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution).

Comment: Many thanks for your contributions!